# how can I create a recursive function that takes two positive integers n,d and returns the sum of the parts (1+d)+(11+d)+... until the next is <= n?

Tags: python

For example, sumDelta(50,3) should return the sum 4+14+24+34+44=120
sumDelta(63,12) should return the sum 13+23+33+43+53=165. The next installment is 63 but it no longer counts towards the sum.

```
def sumdelta(n,d):
    if n <= d:
        return d
    else:
        return 1+d + sumdelta(n,d+10)

I tried like that, but it didn't work
```

My return is 173 and shoud be 120

Comment: `if n <= d: return 0` (rather than `return d`) seems correct.

Comment: *Until the next (1+d') >= n?* - `if n <= 1+d: return 0`